# Do dialogues like 那是四本什麼書? 那是四本國語書 sound normal or awkward?

Tags: pronunciation, spoken

I got the following simple Chinese dialog between a mother and her daughter.

甲：這是什麼?
乙：這是一枝毛筆。
甲：這是一枝什麼筆？
乙：這是一枝毛筆。
甲：那是本什麼書。
乙：那是本中文書。
甲：那枝是什麼筆？
乙：那枝是本毛筆。

乙：那四本是中文書。

In the dialog, the locations of the classifiers (本 and 枝) are switching either before the verb OR after the verb (是). I would assume this would be the same case for quantities that are more than 1 (as in the last sentence). For a quantity that is more than 1, can I say:

甲：那四本是什麼書?
乙：那四本是國語書。
甲：那是四本什麼書?
乙：那是四本國語書。

Do the above sentences sound completely normal or awkward even though they'd be grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions of the dialogue sound correct.

Though there is a subtle pragmatic difference between these sentences. When you put the numeral and/or the quantifier in the position of the topic (before 是) and combined with the demonstrative 那 (or 這), the quantity and location of what you're asking about gets (slightly) emphasized. So when you ask about 那四本書, a listener might infer that there are more than four books in the vicinity, and you are pointing out four specific ones. On the other hand, when you ask 那是四本什麼書, a listener is less likely to make such an inference, but will simply think that you are being a little redundant in specifying the number of books, or will perhaps understand that you recognize the four books to be of the same category.

The other pairs of dialogues have similar subtleties. 那枝是什麼筆 and 那本是什麼書 (weakly) imply the existence of other writing instruments and books in the environment, whereas 那是枝什麼筆 and 那是本什麼書 don't have the same connotation.

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer. So does dialog 2 sound natural to you as a native chinese speaker? dialog 1 is copied from a textbook published in Taiwan so I assume it would sound a bit awkward to native speakers from mainland china. I don't know... Are you speaking Taiwanese Mandarin?

Comment: Both sound natural to me. I grew up to Standard Mandarin as spoken in Mainland China, for what it's worth. I also suspect there isn't a significant difference between Taiwanese and Mainland Mandarin in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my editing to the practicing material:

[image]